# javascript ou php - como ler boletos de conta de consumo

Tags: php, javascript

Caros, alguém saberia dizer como ler código de barras de contas de consumo (luz, gás etc.) para obter valor, data de vencimento etc. em javascript ou php? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu particularmente gosto bastante **[desta biblioteca](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode)**, simples de usar e eficaz:

Simplesmente tens de criar uma tag *img*, *svg* ou *canvas* e informares ao **javascript**

```
<svg id="barcode"></svg>
<!-- ou -->
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<!-- ou -->
<img id="barcode"/>
```

### Javascript

```
JsBarcode("#barcode", "ola!");
// ou jQuery
$("#barcode").JsBarcode("ola!");
```

**Exemplo retirado da própria documentação da biblioteca!**

Comment: Obrigado, mas ela serve para boletos de contas de energia, por exemplo, que têm 48 números, sendo 44 válidos e 4 dígitos verificadores? Se sim, qual seria o tipo?